# Thumbnail not found

Tags: android, image, thumbnails, android-sdcard, universal-image-loader

I'm using universal image loader to display SD card images in grid,

I'm using below code.

```
this.imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

        //int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);

        for (int i = 0; i < imagecursor.getCount(); i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);

            Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail(
                    getContentResolver(), Long.valueOf(imagecursor.getString(image_column_index)),
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                    null );

            if( cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();//**EDIT**
                String uri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
                imageUrls.add(uri);
            }

        }
```

its not loading all the thumbnails, when I check Android studio logs I see similar exception for multiple times

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/.thumbnails/1445029040607.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01
```

where I'm going wrong?